# Django: Show posts with maximum upvotes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am working on a project and I am a beginner in Django. In the project, the user can create product posts and other users can upvote it. On the homepage, I wanna show posts with maximum upvotes. I am using Postgresql as a backend.

this is the view function for the homepage that returns products dictionary:

```
def home(request):
products = Product.objects
return render(request, 'products/home.html', {'products': products})
```

as I am a beginner I am not getting any idea of how to do it in Django templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanna show posts with maximum upvotes

Assuming `Product` model has a `votes` field of `IntegerField` type, you can use something as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Max

max_votes = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Max('votes'))
products = Product.objects.filter(votes=max_votes)
```

If the idea is to show top `n` upvoted `Product`s then use following query

```
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-votes')[:n]
```

The negative sign in front of "-votes" in above query indicates descending order.

Comment: how can I do this operation in the template directly?  because I don't wanna return posts with maximum upvotes from views.py.. what I want to do is write some code in the template that performs some operation on products dict and return three maximum upvoted posts.

Comment: No you can't do this (at least in the form I've stated in answer) in Django templates. You'll have to do get `Queryset` in views only.

Comment: I made a filter that will take a queryset and sort it and returns only three upvoted posts. But I did used that order_by method to sort them so thankyou. The reason why i was not returning it from views.py is that I want to use that dict as it is without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`orderby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method provided in django ORM.

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('fieldname')   #This is ascending
```

For Dscending you put `-` in front of fieldname.Which will get you max results first for this field.

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('-fieldname')   #This is ascending
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.order_by('votes') 
    return render(request, 'products/home.html', {'products': products})
```